# Angular app on Kubernetes Ingress when using non-root path

Tags: angular, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an Angular app which works perfectly in the development environment.

When I try to deploy it to a Kubernetes cluster and create an ingress route for it, things don't work as expected.

Specifically, I'm using this ingress definition

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: angular-website
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: angular-website
          servicePort: 80
        path: /website(/($|.*))?
```

When I try to go to that ingress route, I see a blank page and it the network tab (in Chrome), I see these errors

[image]

I realize that this is happening because I'm trying to route on a non-root path (i.e. something that isn't `/`), and Angular isn't "aware" of that and assumes that the app runs from the root path when it tries to load all the JS bundles.

I realize that I can fix this by editing a section in the main `index.html` in my application from

```html
<base href="/">
```

to

```html
<base href="/website">
```

But I rather not do that since it would require me to know the path ahead of time, during build.

Is there a way around it? Is there a way to make Angular dynamically be aware of the root path without having to recompile the app to set that?

**Edit**

The Angular app is hosted in a NodeJS Express application

```js
const clientPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "public", "angular-website", "dist", "angular-website");

app.use(express.static(clientPath));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(clientPath, "index.html"));
```

Comment: Is the angular configured with nginx or apache server? If possible can you provide the DockerFile

Comment: @Prashanna just edited the post. I use NodeJS+Express to use the Angular app (I have a snippet of the routing code). the docker file is a standard NodeJS docker file, I can share if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up building the Angular app in my Dockerfile like this

```
RUN npm run build -- --prod --base-href="/{{basePath}}" --deploy-url="{{basePath}}/"
```

basically, during build, I pass a placeholder to the `--base-href` and `--deploy-url` arguments which indicate what's the root path of my app.

Then, when I serve the Angular app from my NodeJS + Express process, I use [mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache-express) (a templating engine) to substitute there placeholders with a the root path of my app that's stored in an environment variable.

```
res.render('index', {
    basePath: process.env.CLIENT_BASE_PATH || ''
});
```